# Determine the index where two lists diverge

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, linked-list

## Background

A class provides an API to determine the index where two string lists diverge.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * Provides the ability to determine the index whereat two lists begin
 * to differ in content. Both this list and the list to comapre against
 * must not contain null strings.
 */
public class DivergentList extends LinkedList<String> {
  /**
   * Answers the index at which the strings within this list differ from
   * the strings in the given list.
   *
   * @param list The list to compare against.
   *
   * @return -1 if the lists have no common strings.
   */
  public int diverges( DivergentList list ) {
    int index = -1;

    if( valid( list ) && valid( this ) ) {
      while( equals( list, ++index ) );
    }

    return index;
  }

  /**
   * Answers whether the element at the given index is the same in both
   * lists. This is not null-safe.
   *
   * @param list The list to compare against this list.
   * @return true The lists have the same string at the given index.
   */
  private boolean equals( DivergentList list, int index ) {
    return (index < size()) && (index < list.size()) &&
      get( index ).equals( list.get( index ) );
  }

  /**
   * Answers whether the given element path contains at least one
   * string.
   *
   * @param list The list that must have at least one string.
   * @return true The list has at least one element.
   */
  private boolean valid( DivergentList list ) {
    return list != null && list.size() > 0;
  }

  /**
   * Test the functionality.
   */
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    DivergentList list1 = new DivergentList();
    list1.addLast( "name" );
    list1.addLast( "first" );
    list1.addLast( "middle" );
    list1.addLast( "last" );
    list1.addLast( "maiden" );

    DivergentList list2 = new DivergentList();
    list2.addLast( "name" );
    list2.addLast( "middle" );
    list2.addLast( "last" );

    // Prints 1
    out.println( list2.diverges( list1 ) );

    list1.clear();
    list1.addLast( "name" );
    list1.addLast( "middle" );
    list1.addLast( "last" );

    list2.clear();
    list2.addLast( "name" );
    list2.addLast( "middle" );
    list2.addLast( "last" );
    list2.addLast( "maiden" );
    list2.addLast( "honorific" );

    // Prints 3
    out.println( list2.diverges( list1 ) );

    list1.clear();
    list2.clear();

    // Prints -1
    out.println( list1.diverges( list2 ) );

    list1.add( "name" );
    list2.add( "address" );

    // Prints 0
    out.println( list1.diverges( list2 ) );

    list2.addFirst( "name" );

    // Prints 1
    out.println( list1.diverges( list2 ) );
  }
}
```

## Questions

A few questions:

- How can the code be simplified (e.g., use a different structure)?
- How can the code be improved (e.g., use generics; change the name, etc.)?
- How would you make the code null-safe (e.g., override all `add` methods)?
- How would you optimize the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

- Use `ArrayList`. LinkedList is not random access list. `LinkedList#get(index)` has O(n), `ArrayList#get(index)` has O(1)
- The second check `valid(this)` is not required
- Use Iterator to avoid `(index < size()) && (index < list.size())`
- Not sure it is really necessary to define a new Class. Simple static util method can also do the job
- [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java)

Example:

```
static int firstMismatch(List<?> original, List<?> other) {

    int index      = -1;
    Iterator<?> it = other.iterator();

    for(Object el : original){

        ++index;

        if(!(it.hasNext() && el.equals(it.next()))){
            return index;
        } 
    }

    // TODO: other.size() > original.size()
    return it.hasNext() ? (index + 1) : -1; 
}
```

Prints:

```
Original: [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
Other:    [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
-1
---------
Original: [name, middle, last]
Other:    [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
1
---------
Original: [name, middle, last, maiden, honorific]
Other:    [name, middle, last]
3
---------
Original: []
Other:    []
-1
---------
Original: [name]
Other:    [address]
0
---------
Original: [name]
Other:    [name, address]
1 // TODO: original has only 1 element
```

---

For completeness, another approach is to determine the list with fewer items, then iterate against the larger of the two, and exit when no more matches are found:

```
public int diverges( DivergentList<E> list ) {
  int index = -1;

  // Determine the larger list for iterating.
  boolean smaller = list.size() < this.size();

  Iterator<E> iFew = (smaller ? list : this).iterator();

  // Iterate over the larger list.
  for( E e : (smaller ? this : list) ) {
    // Terminate when no more items exist in the smaller list.
    if( !(iFew.hasNext() && e.equals( iFew.next() )) ) {
      break;
    }

    index++;
  }

  return index;
}
```

This introduces a new variable, uses a single return statement, eliminates a final return calculation, and ensures `list1.diverges( list2 ) == list2.diverges( list1 )` is always true.

The revised code prints:

```
Original: [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
Other:    [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
4
---------
Original: [name, middle, last]
Other:    [name, first, middle, last, maiden]
0
---------
Original: [name, middle, last, maiden, honorific]
Other:    [name, middle, last]
2
---------
Original: []
Other:    []
-1
---------
Original: [name]
Other:    [address]
-1
---------
Original: [name]
Other:    [name, address]
0
```

In this case, the return values indicate the last common index, which allows an empty list to be differentiated from an equal list.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with everything except the idea of a utility method. The static method would need a place to call home, which implies a utility class. For me, a class must have attributes *and* behaviours to be considered object-oriented. (As per [Alan Kay's definition](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented).) But this waxes philosophical and is too deep a topic for a single comment.